# Bring trails onto a Garmin nuvi GPS

Tags: qgis, kml, kmz, garmin, software-recommendations

I seem to be having a lot of trouble uploading Utah Trails onto my nuvi 50 GPS.  Is it not possible?  The Black hills national forest has a img file that is able to be loaded onto the GPS, but the maps I have for Utah, are in kmz.  I have converted them into a gpx, and QGIS tries to upload them, but it seems that the only thing that goes across is way points.  Do I need to convert it to an img files?  Is there a way to do this in QGIS or something else?

Thanks for any help, I am not sure how many hours I have spent spinning my wheels here.

Comment: GPSBabel  will help you get your data uploaded http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/fmt_garmin.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that specific model, but many Garmin Nuvis do not allow uploading tracks or routes. It is only possible to upload waypoints/favourite locations. So to add your trails you would have to create a map as Garmin IMG file.

There are a few tools which can do this. One free option is [Javawa IMGfromGPX](http://www.javawa.nl/imgfromgpx_en.html). Just specify your GPX track files as inputs, and set track colours if you want, and tick the option for "Include creation of gmapsupp.img file". Then you can create the map.

You need to copy the gmapsupp.img file to your GPS device. This needs to be in the "Map" directory, either on the internal memory or the memory card. You might need to rename the gmapsupp.img file, if there is already a map with that name. It should work with any name, so long as it ends as .img